# sqlalchemy integrity error when using many to many relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, many-to-many

I'm writting application to store leaked DBs and hashes in MySQL. I want to save some space, so I figured out it may be a good idea to store only unique hashes in `Hashes` table and put a reference from `DBList` table. In other words, if I want to get all hashes that belongs to `db_id=1` I should ask for them using association table.

For testing purposes I've created these files:

- [create_fresh_db.py](https://pastebin.com/T96AK5dv)
- [mydb.py](https://pastebin.com/0JsTi0K1)
- [regex_test.txt](https://pastebin.com/9R6nmjFr)

My problem is that association table called `dbtohash` is filled properly only when I'm inserting unique hashes. If I'm trying to create different name for DB and using the same hashlist (regex_test.txt) an `IntegrityError` exception is raised. How can I fix that?

**EDIT**: Following suggestion given in comments. Here are relevant parts of my code. This is how I create many-to-many relationship and association table:

```
dbtohash = db.Table(
    'dbtohash',
    db.Column(
        'hash_id',
        db.Integer,
        db.ForeignKey('Hashes.hash_id')),
    db.Column(
        'db_id',
        db.Integer,
        db.ForeignKey('DBList.db_id')))

class DBList(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'DBList'
    db_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    db_name = db.Column(db.String(128), index=True, unique=True)

class Hashes(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Hashes'
    hash_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    hash_val = db.Column(db.String(1024), unique=True)
    hash_salt = db.Column(db.String(256))
    hash_plain = db.Column(db.String(256))
    subscriptions = db.relationship(
        'DBList', secondary=dbtohash, backref=db.backref(
            'dbtohashref', lazy='dynamic'))
```

And this is how I insert data to it:

new list

```
# if we have some matched hashes...
if len(hash_pass) > 0:
    # create new list
    newlist = DBList(
        db_name = '{}_{}'.format('db', datetime.utcnow()),
    )
    print('newlist: {}'.format(newlist))
    # try to insert DB name to DBList table, raise exception if name is taken
    try:
        db.session.add(newlist)
        db.session.commit()
        db.session.flush()
    except IntegrityError:
        db.session.rollback()
        print('this DB name is taken, choose another one', 'danger')
```

insert hashes to DB

```
failed=[]
for hash in hash_pass:
    inserthash = Hashes (
        hash_val = hash,
    )
    try:
        db.session.add(inserthash)
        db.session.commit()
        db.session.flush()
        hashid=inserthash.hash_id
    except IntegrityError:
        db.session.rollback()
        failed.append(hash)
        hashid=db.session.query(Hashes.hash_id).filter_by(hash_val=hash).one()[0]
    # fill up association table
    newlist.dbtohashref.append(inserthash)
    db.session.commit()
if failed:
    print('failed: {}'.format(failed))
```

problematic line is: `newlist.dbtohashref.append(inserthash)`

EDIT 2: full trace attached

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mydb.py", line 88, in <module>
    db.session.commit()
  File "/home/user/envs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.py", line 153, in do
    return getattr(self.registry(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/envs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 943, in commit
    self.transaction.commit()
  File "/home/user/envs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 467, in commit
    self._prepare_impl()
  File "/home/user/envs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 447, in _prepare_impl
    self.session.flush()
  File "/home/user/envs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2254, in flush
    self._flush(objects)
  File "/home/user/envs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2380, in _flush
    transaction.rollback(_capture_exception=True)
  File "/home/user/envs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 66, in __exit__
    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
  File "/home/user/envs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2344, in _flush
    flush_context.execute()
  File "/home/user/envs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 391, in execute
    rec.execute(self)
  File "/home/user/envs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 556, in execute
    uow
  File "/home/user/envs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 181, in save_obj
    mapper, table, insert)
  File "/home/user/envs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 866, in _emit_insert_statements
    execute(statement, params)
  File "/home/user/envs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 948, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/home/user/envs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 269, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/home/user/envs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1060, in _execute_clauseelement
    compiled_sql, distilled_params
  File "/home/user/envs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1200, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/home/user/envs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1413, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    exc_info
  File "/home/user/envs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 203, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "/home/user/envs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1193, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/home/user/envs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 507, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
  File "/home/user/envs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 165, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
  File "/home/user/envs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 321, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "/home/user/envs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 860, in query
    self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
  File "/home/user/envs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1061, in _read_query_result
    result.read()
  File "/home/user/envs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1349, in read
    first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
  File "/home/user/envs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1018, in _read_packet
    packet.check_error()
  File "/home/user/envs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 384, in check_error
    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
  File "/home/user/envs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/err.py", line 107, in raise_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno, errval)
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (pymysql.err.IntegrityError) (1062, u"Duplicate entry 'd38b70e33d7ae06c1696910eb6f93ca4' for key 'hash_val'") [SQL: u'INSERT INTO `Hashes` (hash_val, hash_salt, hash_plain) VALUES (%(hash_val)s, %(hash_salt)s, %(hash_plain)s)'] [parameters: {'hash_salt': None, 'hash_val': 'd38b70e33d7ae06c1696910eb6f93ca4', 'hash_plain': None}] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/gkpj)
```

Comment: [Please include relevant code in the post itself as text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), or in other words produce a [mcve]. Also provide full tracebacks, not just the name of the exception.

Comment: @IljaEverilä Edited as requested

Comment: On a quick glance it looks like you effectively ignore the error while inserting hashes and append the failed `inserthash` instance to `newlist.dbtohashref` collection anyway. Since it is still a transient/pending instance (not sure how it goes on rollback), the following commit will try to INSERT it to the DB, again. Can't say for sure though, since you've not included the *full traceback*.

Comment: @IljaEverilä yes, you are right that ```newlist.dbtohashref.append(inserthash)``` is trying to insert values again. So what I did was to replace ```try: db.session.add(inserthash)``` with ```try: newlist.dbtohashref.append(inserthash)``` and it is now inserting hash only once, but still when I run this script on the same set o hashes, it gives me error like above. I'm not sure how to handle this integrity error and still fill up association table correctly.